# while pushing the data in to arrays, not added in order

Tags: javascript, arrays

enter image description here

i need to push the data one after another, but here i am getting to add in disorder like last added array in to first.

```js
for (var key in data[tabName + scoreBreakDown]) {
  var values = data[tabName + scoreBreakDown][key];
  var staticData = values[0];
  var obj = [];
  obj.push(staticData.CompanyName);
  obj.push(staticData.Country_ORIG);
  for (var value in values) {
    if (addHeader) {
      headersArray.push(values[value].AspectName);
      weightArray.push(values[value].ScoreWeight);
    }
    obj.push(values[value].SPESGScore_ORIG);
  }
  addHeader = false;
  dataArray.push(obj);
}
```

[image]

Comment: try unshift: to add in front "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btX05.png for attachment

Comment: question is not clear, please add more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.map to map through an array and transform it into a new array in order.

In this example, we are just multiplying each value by 3, but the transformation is arbitrary.

```js
let loop = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(item => {
    return item*3
  })
}

console.log(loop([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

If you want to loop through an object in order this way, you can use Object.keys() this will return an array of the keys in the object.

```js
let loop = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(item => {
    return `${item}: ${obj[item]}`
  })
}

let obj = {
  first_name:"John",
  last_name:"Doe",
  age:23
}

console.log(loop(obj))
```

So instead of using a for loop and an if statement to check a condition and push the data to the array after each iteration, you can use something Array.filter() to remove entries you don't want to push, and return them in order.

```js
data = [
  {header:true, value:"item1"}, 
  {header:false, value:"item2"},
  {header:true, value:"item3"},
 ]

let array = data.filter(item => {return item.header}).map(item => {
  return item.value
})

console.log(array)
```